# How to get count for all products for all categories (i.e all records on many-to-many table) with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This what i want to do is to take the count of records from many-to-many table. I can do it with a simple query, but I want to use the ORM of Laravel 5.2. These are my models:

Category model

```
class Category extends BaseModel {
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_category');
    }
```

Product model

```
class Product extends BaseModel {
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category', 'product_category')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I want to add a method in the Category model or using the Laravel ORM to take the number of all products for all categories i.e the number of all records from the `product_category` table. How can I do it ?

Comment: So if I understand this right, you want to have the number of all products in a category?

Comment: No. I want to get all products for all categories. Not only all products in a category. I know how to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you right, you want a method that will return the number of all records in the `product_category` table. If that is the case, here you go:

```
public function numberOfProductCategories() {
    return DB::table('product_category')->count();
}
```

You may find more info about this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much.